# Wave vector components from 2 column data

Tags: waves, kinematics, vectors, data-analysis

if I have 10 data in each column for speed (2D), how to connect those data as wave form?

I need to find the components of wave vector ($k_x, K_y$).

I request any suggestions regarding this.